# Appending data to a file in Matlab, removing before a symbol

Tags: matlab, file, byte

I have a file which is written via Matlab from a vector `M` with binary data values. This file is written with Matlab's `fwrite` in the following script `myGenFile.m` of the form `function myGenFile(fName, M)`:

```
% open output file
fId = fopen(fName, 'W');

% start by writing some things to the file    
fprintf(fId, '{DATA BITLENGTH:%d}', length(M));
fprintf(fId, '{DATA LIST-%d:#', ceil(length(M) / 8) + 1);

% pad to full bytes
lenRest = mod(length(M), 8);
M = [M, zeros(1, 8 - lenRest)];

% reverse order in bytes
M = reshape(M, 8, ceil(length(M) / 8));
MReversed = zeros(8, ceil(length(M) / 8));
for i = 1:8
    MReversed(i,:) = M(9-i,:);
end
MM = reshape(MReversed, 1, 8*len8);

fwrite(fId, MM, 'ubit1');

% write some ending of the file
fprintf(fId, '}');
fclose(fId);
```

Now I want to write a file `myAppendFile.m`, which appends some values to the existing file and has the following form: `function myAppendFile(newData, fName)`. To do this I will have to remove the trailing '}':

```
fId = fopen(nameFile,'r');
oldData = textscan(fId, '%s', 'Delimiter', '\n');
% remove the last character of the file; aka the ending '}'
oldData{end}{end} = oldData{end}{end}(1:end-1);
```

The problem is now when trying to write `oldData` into the file (writing `newData` should be trivial, since it is also a vector of binary data like `M`), since it is a cell of cell arrays, containing strings.

How could I overcome this issue and append the new data correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `textscan` which copies the file to your memory, then writes it back, you could use `fseek` to set the pointer where you want to continue writing. Just put it one char before end of file and continue writing.

```
fseek(fid, -1, 'eof');
```

Comment: Agreed, this is a much better approach! However, when testing `fseek(fId, -1, 'eof')`, the new data is not appended to the desired place before the '}', but at the end of the file. Is it true that in this case I have to open the file with `fId = fopen(fileName, 'a+')`?

Comment: Maybe the `-1` is not right because there are whitespace characters (new line) at the end. You could try seeking back 10 chars, then read the last 10 chars using `A = fread(fid, 10, 'uint8=>char');`